# Using Go on Windows 11 with gocv for OpenCV cannot find header opencv.hpp even with CGO_CXXFLAGS set

Tags: opencv, go, msys2, windows-11, gocv

When running `go run`, not found.
But when listing `dir`, the header is right there...

```
PS C:\Users\phili\SourceCode\goopencv> set CGO_CPPFLAGS="-IC:/Users/phili/SourceCode/opencv/build/include"

PS C:\Users\phili\SourceCode\goopencv> go run -tags customenv "C:\Users\phili\go\pkg\mod\gocv.io\x\gocv@v0.35.0\cmd\version\main.go"

# gocv.io/x/gocv
In file included from aruco.cpp:1:0:
aruco.h:5:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

/*        */

PS C:\Users\phili\SourceCode\goopencv> dir C:\Users\phili\SourceCode\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp

    Directory: C:\Users\phili\SourceCode\opencv\build\include\opencv2

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         9/27/2023   9:54 AM           3558 opencv.hpp

PS C:\Users\phili\SourceCode\goopencv>
```

I also tried installing in MSYS2 and got a different error:

```
phili@PhilBook3 UCRT64 ~/gocv
$ go run "C:\msys64\ucrt64\lib\go\pkg\mod\gocv.io\x\gocv@v0.35.0\cmd\version\main.go"

# gocv.io/x/gocv
C:\Users\phili\go\pkg\mod\gocv.io\x\gocv@v0.35.0\calib3d_string.go:3:9: undefined: CalibFlag
C:\Users\phili\go\pkg\mod\gocv.io\x\gocv@v0.35.0\calib3d_string.go:29:9: undefined: CalibCBFlag
...
C:\Users\phili\go\pkg\mod\gocv.io\x\gocv@v0.35.0\core_string.go:159:9: too many errors
```

I'm just trying to get it running on windows anyway possible.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

same error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" run D:\Golang\opencv\test.go
gocv.io/x/gocv
In file included from aruco.cpp:1:
aruco.h:5:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
5 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

solution:

```
copy your opencv/build/install/inlude/opencv2  directory to \go\pkg\mod\gocv.io\x\gocv@v0.35.0  directory then error disappear
```